# How to get object from array when you don't know the index number

Tags: api, karate

so here is my Actual response of get call

{"message":
{ "Name": "Rodger",
"Salary": "5000"
"id": 54g545f5dfd5e5d
},
{ "Name": "Novak",
"Salary": "4000"
"id": 62g345f7dfd3e5g
}
}

later using post call I added another person who has same name and salary. and its get call response look like

{"message":
{ "Name": "Rodger",
"Salary": "5000"
"id": 54g545f5dfd5e5d
},
{ "Name": "Rodger",
"Salary": "5000"
"id": 27g145f5dfd4e5k
},
{ "Name": "Novak",
"Salary": "4000"
"id": 62g345f7dfd3e5g
}
}

So now I want to get that object who's id is 27g145f5dfd4e5k.
Note: I don't know the index so using id can I get that person.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please next time post VALID JSON. what you have pasted above is not

Comment: Sorry @PeterThomas i will take care of that from next time. thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you spend some time understanding JSON and how to use JS in Karate to access data.

```
* def response = { message: [ { name: 'foo1', id: 'bar1' }, { name: 'foo2', id: 'bar2' } ] }
* def id1 = response.message[0].id
* match id1 == 'bar1'
  
* def id2 = response.message[1].id
* match id2 == 'bar2'
```

Comment: do you have any references regarding your suggestion that how to use JS in karate to access data? please Suggest.

Comment: Actually I want to get whole object where id == bar1 can we do that? @peter

Comment: @AshishPatil that is a `filter` question then. please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72139917/143475